# Detect tab change in PageControl

Tags: delphi, tpagecontrol

I have a PageControl on my form and i wish to detect when the user is selecting another tab.

How can i do this ? I am using Delphi 7.

I didn't find any event and waisting time developing my own pagecontrol is not exactly what i intend to do.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383659/delphi-how-to-allow-forbid-user-to-enter-tab-in-pagecontrol/8384240#comment10355286_8384240

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try
this on show or create event of your form

```
 iThCrrntIndex:=PageControl1.TabIndex;  //the currently selected page
```

then on **PageControl1Change event** or **PageControl1Changing** event
 check

```
   if   iThCrrntIndex=PageControl1.TabIndex then
        begin
     //same page
   end
 else
   begin
     //new page selected..
   end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `OnChange` and `OnChanging` events?

Comment: Those events happen when the user manually clicks to change the tabs. Not raised when the Page Control is 'programmatically' changed.